Tell SDSC from SDHC (read bit CCS) without re-initializing the SD card
Is there a way to figure out whether an SD card is an SDSC or an SDHC (or superior) without using the ACMD41 command?
Essentially I find myself in a place where a card has already been initialized (ie. by a bootloader) in SD mode and I do not want to reset and start over with the init sequence. In this case I do not know whether the card is an SDSC or not (which I need to isse read/write commands with proper addressing).
I found CMD58 which allows reading the OCR register, but seems to be an optional command (and only available in SPI mode?) so doesn't fit the bill. I would like to avoid re-initializing the cart or passing over information from the bootloader if possible.

Q: what's the reason for wondering? Shouldn't the main difference between SD and SDHC be that SDHC supports >= 4 GB cards through a differently card specific data descriptor format? In other words, if it works, it works?

I ask because figuring out how to address the functional difference you want to address with your SDSC/SDHC detection might yield a robust method, without resorting to first determining the SD version

When using SDHC cards you address them using 512byte blocks, but SDSC cards use byte offsets. So reading or writing data requires knowing the card type so the correct addressing mode can be used.

so, try to set a block size != 512 with CMD16, and see whether reading works the same?

A bit of a hack... Could I use cmd9 to read the CSD register? It has a v2 response that seems to only exist for SDHC/XC cards? That might be easier perhaps. It's also a mandatory command.

sounds like an approach!

The "simplest" way seems to be by reading the CSD register (using CMD9). This register has two versions (1 and 2), version 2 is used for SDHC or SDXC cards, since it encodes card size differently. Retrieving it and checking for the version number seems to be pretty straightforward and requires no reset.
Note: this command only works in standby mode, so it might be necessary to issue a CMD7 if the card is in transfer mode.
